# How to get the javascript alert value in php variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have a `select` box with value

```
<select onchange="javascript:get_id_val(this)" id="variation_select_61_10" name="variation[10]" class="wpsc_select_variation">
    <option value="0" disabled="disabled">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="13">L</option>
    <option value="12">M</option>
    <option value="11">S</option>
</select>
```

I am using java script to get the value of select box

```
function get_id_val(val){
    alert(val.value);   
}
```

How can I get he value of alert which is option value in php variable for use in mysql query?

Comment: You need to send the data to your server via `POST` or using a ajax call. So you need a server round trip.

Comment: hey vikas you can this if you are using ajax...

Comment: you need some thing like `ajax` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026600/form-submit-without-refresh-using-jquery-ajax-if-page-have-more-than-one-form/12030228#12030228

Comment: can i do this without ajax ?

Comment: @Vickey you can look at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it with `ajax`  make sure you have included `jquery`

```
function get_id_val(val){
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: your.php,
    data: "&val=" + val, 
    success: function(data) {
        alert("data")
    }
} );
}
// in your php file
echo     $_POST['val'];
//mysql_query("....");
```

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

if it for only getting the value of the selected option then simply go through with this
in the javascript

```
var Value = $("#variation_select_61_10").val();
alert(Value);
```

no need to pass any value in the onchange function

Answer (score 0):

on change function you can assign the value of select box and then submit the form at the php you can retrieve that value in post data

```
  function get_id_val(val){
      document.getElementById('variation_select_61_10').value = val.value;
     document.getElementById('form-id').submit();

    }
```

on php

```
$value = $_POST['variation'];
```

Comment: can i do it without form submission

Comment: or any other way without ajax

Comment: no there is only two way one using ajax second is form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax,

**index.php**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
function get_id_val(val){   
    var option = val.options[val.selectedIndex];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "sql.php",
        data: "value="+option.value,
        success: function(message){ 
            $("#result").html(message);
        }       
    });

}
</script>
<select onchange="javascript:get_id_val(this)" id="variation_select_61_10" name="variation[10]" class="wpsc_select_variation">
    <option value="0" disabled="disabled">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="13">L</option>
    <option value="12">M</option>
    <option value="11">S</option>
</select>

<div  id="result">
*/result shows here /*
</div>
```

**sql.php**

```
<?php 
$value = $_POST['value'];
echo " INSERT INTO ..... WHERE value = '$value' ";

?>
```

I hope this will help you.